# sql order query in periodic order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have table contains Country, City, Street, Door Number etc. And in every street i have three types of address. One of them is main(permanent), and the others are replacement(temporary)1 and replacement(temporary)2.

I want to order them by city and street

I'm having the following result:

```
City       street             address type

sincan     plevne street      replacement1
sincan     plevne street      main
sincan     plevne street      replacement2
sincan     bosna  street      replacement2
sincan     bosna  street      main
sincan     bosna  street      replacement1
sincan     yazi   street      replacement2
sincan     yazi   street      replacement1
sincan     yazi   street      main
```

But I want to order them like following one.

```
sincan     plevne street      main
sincan     plevne street      replacement1
sincan     plevne street      replacement2
sincan     bosna  street      main
sincan     bosna  street      replacement1
sincan     bosna  street      replacement2
sincan     yazi   street      main
sincan     yazi   street      replacement1
sincan     yazi   street      replacement2
```

is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause

```
ORDER BY city, street, 
    CASE adress_type
        WHEN 'main' THEN 1
        WHEN 'replacement1' THEN 2
        WHEN 'replacement2' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END
```